# Dataframe to json using python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I a dataframe of below format

[image]

I want to send each row separately as below:

```
{ 'timestamp': 'A'
  'tags': {
         'columnA': '1',
         'columnB': '11',
         'columnC': '21'
          .
          .
          .
          .}}
```

The columns vary and I cannot hard code it. Then Send it to firestore collection

Then second row in above format to firestore collection and so on

How can I do this?
and don't mark the question as duplicate without comparing questions

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on the firebase part, but I think this might be what you want

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

# Data frame to work with
x = pd.DataFrame(data={'timestamp': 'A', 'ca': 1, 'cb': 2, 'cc': 3}, index=[0])
x = x.append(x, ignore_index=True)
# rearranging
x = x[['timestamp', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']]

def new_json(row):
    return json.dumps(
        dict(timestamp=row['timestamp'], tag=dict(zip(row.index[1:], row[row.index[1:]].values.tolist()))))


print x.apply(new_json, raw=False, axis=1)
```

#### Output

Output is a pandas series with each entry being a *str* in the json format as needed

```
0 '{"timestamp": "A", "tag": {"cc": 3, "cb": 2, "ca": 1}}'
1 '{"timestamp": "A", "tag": {"cc": 3, "cb": 2, "ca": 1}}'
```